# Sharepoint 2019 timeout windows authentication NTLM

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

i am using sharepoint 2019, my customer want me to configure idle timeout for this environment, currently i am using windows claim NTLM authentication method, based on my research, if i am using windows claim, i will not able to configured session timeout, i dont know which direction i should go now

i have internal and external user that will login to my sharepoint environment, what others authentication method i can try and configure timeout for it? greatly appreciate if you can enlightened me

Answer (score 0):

SAML 1.1 and Forms-based Authentication both support setting timeouts; SAML from the Identity Provider (i.e. AD FS) and FBA from your FBA provider.